# Is it possible to work on one FMX form with different Delphi versions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, delphi-10.1-berlin

I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin. A friend of mine has got Delphi XE4.

I want to modify the code belonging to a FMX form. The code and the form was written in XE4 and needs to stay compilable in XE4. If I edit the code inside the 10.1 IDE and save my changes, Delphi modifies the source code (adding units) and converts the form (FMX file)
to a new format. If this modified form is compiled in XE4 this leads to several errors.

Is it possible to tell Delphi not to do these modifications?

**BTW:**

- If I edit the code outside the IDE everything seems to work fine.
- Delphi 10.1 is adding units (eg `FMX.ComboEdit, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation`) even if these are already there but ifdefed, for example:

  ```
    {$IFDEF DELPHIX_BERLIN_UP} 
    FMX.ComboEdit, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation
    {$ENDIF}
    FMX.ActnList;
  ```

  is modified to

  ```
    {$IFDEF DELPHIX_BERLIN_UP} 
    FMX.ComboEdit, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation
    {$ENDIF}
    FMX.ActnList, FMX.ComboEdit, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation;
  ```

  leading to a compiler error:

  ```
    E2004: Identifier redeclared: FMX.ComboEdit ...
  ```

Comment: You should not have much code in a form unit anyway, so having dual forms for the different versions seems easier to maintain. FMX is still evolving and perhaps one day it will stabilize and be backward compatible.

Comment: No, it's not possible to keep the IDE from making these changes. It's not aware of your conditionals (the `{$IFDEF...}`), because those are for the compiler and not the IDE. Recent versions of FMX have relocated many definitions, and what was in one place in XE4 may be somewhere else entirely (and even implemented totally differently) in XE5 or later.

Comment: @LURD I do not agree. Having dual forms is not really an option for a real project (even with nearly no code in the form unit).

Comment: @AloisHeimer, what choice do you have here? Not only you have to struggle with the IDE, making modifications, but in some components the structure is totally different. Ok, you could use `$IFDEF`, but at some point will the effort keeping one form for both versions overcome the effort maintaining separate forms.

Comment: @LURD You are right. But at the moment `$IFDEF`s are enough for me. There is not much code inside the form units. But I fear the only longtime solution will be to agree on one IDE version :(

Comment: Delphi could make things much more easy, if for instance a form had a setting `Locked` that would prohibit unintended modifications. Therefore my question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to tell Delphi not to do these modifications?

No, it is not.  DFM/FMX files are IDE-managed and version-specific, and always have been.  You should maintain separate DFM/FMX files for each IDE version.

It is *usually* OK to let an older IDE warn and ignore properties added by an newer IDE.  And there are some third party tools floating around that will strip off newer properties from a DFM/FMX file before you open it in an older IDE.